# what is the background theory that Z3 uses to prove constraints unsat

Tags: constraint-satisfaction

The method to get the sat result is kind of straightforward, you can use some search algorithms like heuristic search to get a solution. But how does z3 get the unsat result like x < 2 && x > 2

I searched for some articles related to z3 but didn't don't know how. I would be very grateful if someone could give me the answer or recommend me relevant information

Answer (score 4):

There are basically two components: the underlying SAT solver procedure (DPLL), and the additional theory-specific procedures.

- For the underlying SAT solver: considering your example of `x < 2 && x > 2`, when viewed as a SAT formula this is just $p \land q$. The SAT solver will determine from this that both $p$ and $q$ have to be true.
- For the additional piece: once the SAT solver has done its job, the SMT solver has a set of constraints $p = $`x < 2` and $q = $`x > 2` that have been accumulated by the SAT solver, that it needs to satisfy. It runs a procedure to collect all these constraints and determine whether they are (i) unsatisfiable or (ii) satisfiable.
  (This step is specific to the theory that is recognized: so we would apply a different procedure to deal with `<` constraints, or something like a polynomial with `+` and `*`, or something like lists or strings; each gets its own procedure.)

  In your example, of course we could directly see that the set of constraints `x < 2` and `x > 2` contains a contradictory pair of bounds on the same variable; we could even check for this directly in a preprocessing step. But the more general case would apply a solver for a theory known as [linear real arithmetic](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ebjhua/courses/theory/2021/ref/chap-arith.pdf) or use the [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm).
  The basic idea is to translate all the constraints into a matrix form, such as for your example:
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\1\end{bmatrix} [x] > \begin{bmatrix}-2 \\2\end{bmatrix}
  $$
  we can even simplify this further, by adding additional variables like $y$ for the difference between $x$ and $2$, to replace our inequality > with an equality =, and end up with a matrix equation of the form
  $$
  A\vec{v} = b \text{ subject to } \vec{v} \ge 0
  $$

  The simplex algorithm continues from here, using techniques from linear algebra to determine whether there exists a solution vector $\vec{v}$ or not. If so, the original formula is satisfiable, and we plug in the resulting satisfying assignment to see if it's a solution. If not, it's unsatisfiable and we return back to the SAT solver to continue trying any other possible assignments.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about satisfiability modulo theories (SMT). There are similar algorithmic approaches there, and you can refer to [Wikipedia for more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories#Solver_approaches).

In particular, you can have a look at [DPLL(T)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL(T)) which is what z3 uses.